# getting Error "The slice reducer for key "weathReducer" returned undefined during intialization in my expo app"

Tags: redux, expo

running into Error: The slice reducer for key "weatherReducer" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.

```
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:204:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.0.12:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:146332:3 in global code
```

Comment: Show your code for that reducer?

Comment: hi, as mentioned by the single answer below i made a rookie mistake, i dint return a default state (equal to initial-state) for the reducer switch statement. That was the error

Comment: Then please be aware that in modern Redux you don't need to return state, so if your code looks like that answer, you are probably writing an outdated style of Redux that is about 4x the amount of code needed nowadays. Please read https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today

Comment: Wow , thank you very much , let me go through the article and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when writing a reducer function, there is an initialization call which invokes the reducer without an `action` argument. If you're in that call, you must return `initialState`.

```
var initialState = {
  temperature: undefined,
  units: 'celsius',
  isLoading: false,
}

function weatherReducer(state, action) {
  switch(action) {
    case 'SET_TEMPERATURE': 
      return { ...state, temperature: action.temperature }
    // ... 
    default: 
      return state || initialState // <- here
  }
}
```

Comment: this clears the error , thanks !

Comment: @bitbuoy can you please accept the answer as solution? It's the green check under the votes.